# Is it nice to comment accepted answer suggesting yours?

Tags: discussion, comments

[An answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16717654/1983854) just got accepted. Few minutes later someone posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717583/remove-all-chars-that-are-not-a-digit-from-a-string#comment24068666_16717654) saying

> See my answer for a better way with `tr`. :)

I do not have any problem admitting another answer can be more efficient, but I think such behavior is not pretty nice. In my opinion, it does not look for a better solution but to have his/her answer accepted.

What do you think? Please tell me if I am getting it so seriously :D

Comment: Not really nice, but not really important IMO. The accept is the OP's privilege anyway, they can do whatever they want with it. (BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16717662/635608 is the _even better_ answer.)

Comment: I also like the most the answer you indicate. Anyway, from comments I saw the OP wanted it to be with grep/tr - that's why I suppose I got mine accepted, and also because it is simpler for a newbie than the one that claims to be checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not generally considered nice to post ANY comments about accepting or voting [*]. However, the comment you quoted didn't do that - there is no suggestion of changing the accept mark, for example.

If an answer is inaccurate or incomplete, it is ok to comment saying so, and that includes mentioning that your answer fixes the problem. If it is more that there are two ways to do something, a comment that only asserts another answer has a better way is pointless: the answerer made that same assertion by posting the answer. A comment that said "this is longer than my solution" or "this won't work on XYZ - see my solution for one that will" would be ok - it's actually commenting about the answer itself.

I would flag that comment as pointless. But I wouldn't call it "not nice".

[*] - I have seen, on an accepted answer, a comment by that answer's author suggesting it be unaccepted because a later answer is better. This is perhaps the only acceptable comment that mentions accepting or unaccepting.

Comment: Good explanation! Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 6):

Just because your answer was accepted doesn't automatically make it the best solution.

I don't see any problem with another user posting such a comment.  Ideally it would have some small indication of the problem with your answer, but if that information is already discussed in his answer it doesn't *need* to be in the comment.

> it does not look for a better solution but to have his/her answer accepted

While it's possible that this person is fishing for an acceptance, that may not be the case.  What's more important is that future readers of this question that come here looking for a solution are able to pick the best solution.  Knowing that there is a problem with one solution, or that there is a noticeably better solution, could result in these users using a better answer, which is A Good Thing from the site's perspective.  Answerers getting votes/rep is really just a means to that end.